# wireshark syntax for SDP element that appears multiple times

Tags: filter, wireshark, sdp

I am trying to filter a wireshark capture that contains sdp information. The information can appear multiple times in the same packet, I am trying to filter on only the initial value.

As a more concrete example the sdp.media.port attribute may be present multiple times in the same packet with different values, for example first as 12004 for audio and then as 12006 for image. Setting a filter of either `sdp.media.port == 12004` or `sdp.media.port == 12006` will select this packet.

What is the syntax for a filter to only select packets that have 12006 as the initial value? This filter would ignore the above packet if set to 12006, but would select this packet if set to 12004

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select the packets, where Media Type: audio contains the value 12004.
In that case you can use the following display filter:
(sdp.media.media == "audio") && (sdp.media.port == 12004)

BTW
You can use TShark to create a list:
Only first occurrence:
tshark -r test.pcap -Y sdp.media.port -T fields -e frame.number -e sdp.media.media -e sdp.media.port -E occurrence=f
3       audio   5004
6       audio   23010

All occurrences:
tshark -r test.pcap -Y sdp.media.port -T fields -e frame.number -e sdp.media.media -e sdp.media.port -E occurrence=a
3       audio,video     5004,5006
6       audio,video     23010,23030

You can find more information about TShark at the [man-page](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I haven't tested in tshark, from your output it looks like it might work for me if the gui had some way of specifying occurence, since the "audio" line appears first, but in the wireshark gui this does not do what I would like. `(sdp.media.media == "audio") && (sdp.media.port == 12004)` will also select a packet where any included sdp media line uses port 12004, even if port 12004 is not the one associated with the media sdp line that describes "audio"

Comment: Wireshark Specifying occurrence. You first have to add a column: right-click Media Port in the Packet Details Pane, Select Apply As Column. Next you have to edit the column details: right-click column Media Port, select Edit Column Details..., change Occurrence to 1 (first occurrence). Hope this helps, Joke

Comment: Thanks. This works nicely for display purposes.I am leaving the question as unanswered since I'd really like a gui filter solution.